# Azure function app and web app authentication

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way Azure provides to authentication and maintain a session of the user in data base (azure mysql db), across azure web app and the function app ?

For example, I need some central authorisation server which would generate token for the logged in user of the web application , and the same token can be used to authenticate / authorise the function request ( function app).

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Please elaborate a bit more (what kind of authentication, what kind of trigger are you using for your Function App). But to answer your questions... sure: cookies.

Comment: Have you referenced to use [AD to protect the WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)?

Answer (score 0):

Token is a kind of think that is supposed to be used during a particular session, so it has a expiration time. Saving it in some store ( Blob Storage etc) will lead to security issue.
If you wanted to if you want to use the authentication with Function app then you can do it in same as Web app do i.e. using OAuth feature from portal.